# Store and acces variable accross pages via sessions

Tags: php, variables, session

I have this function

```
$username = PSF::requestGetPOST('username');
```

It has the email of user that is being logged in. it is working fine.

now, i want to store this  `$username` into a session so that i can access it on another page.

how i tried

```
$_SESSION["email"] = $username ;
```

and access on the other page

```
$email = $_SESSION["email"] ;
```

doesn't seem to work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need To Put

> session_start();

before any Output is start.

Otherwise You will get header already sent error
Then You can Assign variable to session like below

> $_SESSION["email"] = $username ;

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use sessions, at the beginning of your page you have to use session_start();

For example :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $username ;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this first before using `$_SESSION`

```
session_start();
```

See [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make session work you should do

```
session_start()
```

somewhere in your script or set *session.auto_start* to '1' in php.ini